# Can I create DWORD registry keys with wix?

Tags: wix, registry

I'm trying to create a DWORD registry key by setting `Type` to `dword`. I'm getting:

```
error CNDL0021 : The RegistryValue/@Type attribute's value, 'dword', is not 
                 one of the legal options: 'binary', 'expandable', 'integer', 
                 'multiString', or 'string'.
```

Which of these should I use?

Comment: I really suggest using Visual Studio for editing WiX files, the syntax highlighting and IntelliSense integration would show this as invalid before you even compile. You would even been have presented with a dropdown showing valid values :)

Comment: @saschabeaumont Does this work with VS2005?

Comment: yes, it does :) From memory I think you need the WiX "Votive" plugin installed for VS2005 integration (and the WiX installer should prompt you about this anyway)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the docs for [RegistryValue](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_registryvalue.htm) makes this obvious:

> *integer*
>      The value is interpreted and stored as an integer (REG_DWORD).

Comment: Now for extra fun, try creating a QWord. :O